# Integrating Google pay buttons and Apple pay buttons into react-native application

Tags: react-native, applepay, google-pay, design-guidelines

I have been searching everywhere on how to integrate the native assets provided by Apple (**PkPaymentButton**) and Google Pay ( **https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/brand-guidelines#payment-buttons** ) without having to write my own native modules.

I found out that these two were included in the **react-native-GPay** library, and in the **react-native-payment** libraries(interface for **PKPaymentButton**). 
Problem is, i am already using another library handling Apple pay and Google pay (**tipsi-stripe**) which doesn't provide the interface for the native buttons, and i don't want to include these two libraries just to use their native buttons implementation.

I also want to respect the apple/google brand design guidelines. They are very specific :
 - **Don't** create your own Google Pay buttons or alter the font, color, button radius, or padding within the button in any way.
 - **Don't** create your own Apple Pay button design or attempt to mimic the system-provided button designs.

Everywhere i look, it seems like people providing tutorial on how to implement googlepay/apple pay inside react-native apps don't care about the branding guidelines (they use simple TouchableOpacity with some text inside, triggering the payment interfaces)
And i couldn't find any react-native modules that only implements the buttons UI

**Maybe i am missing something quite obvious (it is my first implementation of these features), but is there any react-native modules that only provide interface for native button assets , without implementing the whole payment libraries ? Would it be usefull to create a react-native module that does just that ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a kind of in the same situation, except that I'm not using GPay from tipsi-stripe in my project, I'm just using it for Apple Pay on iOS. And if it can help you, here's the repo that I just recently published which exposes native Apple Pay button to React Native:
[Apple Pay button for RN](https://github.com/brascene/rn-apple-pay-button)

Regarding Android, I didn't include it since I'm not familiar with native Android. I hope someone will add it as well, or tipsi-will stripe will include it.

Comment: Hello ! I accidentally fell on your repository , and was thinking "that's exactly what i was looking for 6 months ago !", then i saw your comment, 
Thank you very much for your work  !

Comment: For Google pay button, i did a custom native implementation based on the google pay button feature of this repository ( because it was not working at the time i downloaded it, haven't tried again since ) :
https://github.com/hellochirag/react-native-GPay